# how to second Arraylist update in first Arraylist?

Tags: android, arraylist, updates

Two `Arraylist` in app.First `Arraylist is ArrayList<Thumbnail> videoList = new ArrayList<>()` and Second ArrayList is `ArrayList<Giphy> giphylist = new ArrayList()`.

giphylist arraylist item is update in videoList. How it's Update to Second ArrayList GiphyList Item Value in First ArrayList videoList item value?

I tried to addAll() function.can used this function  overwrite Arraylist?
just Like this :`videoList = new ArrayList<Thumbnail>(giphyList);`
this give also error : cannot resolve constructor ArrayList(java.util.List)

Thumbnail.java

```
public class Thumbnail {


    private String gif,videoUrl;
    private int id, thumbUp, thumbDown;

    public Thumbnail (int id,String gif,String videoUrl,int thumbUp,int thumbDown){


        this.gif = gif;
        this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
        this.thumbUp =thumbUp;
        this.thumbDown = thumbDown;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGif() {
        return gif;
    }

    public void setGif(String gif) {
        this.gif = gif;
    }

    public String getVideoUrl() {
        return videoUrl;
    }

    public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
        this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getThumbUp() {
        return thumbUp;
    }

    public int getThumbDown() {
        return thumbDown;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setThumbUp(int thumbUp) {
        this.thumbUp = thumbUp;
    }

    public void setThumbDown(int thumbDown) {
        this.thumbDown = thumbDown;
    }
}
```

Giphy.java

```
@Entity
public class Giphy {

    @Id(assignable = true)
    private long id;
    private String url;
    private int thumbUp;
    private int thumbDown;
    private String gif;


//    public Giphy(){

  //  }

    public Giphy(long id,String gif,String url,int thumbUp,int thumbDown){

        this.id = id;
        this.url = url;
        this.thumbUp = thumbUp;
        this.thumbDown = thumbDown;
        this.gif = gif;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public int getThumbUp() {
        return thumbUp;
    }

    public int getThumbDown() {
        return thumbDown;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setThumbUp(int thumbUp) {
        this.thumbUp = thumbUp;
    }

    public void setThumbDown(int thumbDown) {
        this.thumbDown = thumbDown;
    }

    public String getGif() {
        return gif;
    }

    public void setGif(String gif) {
        this.gif = gif;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @rahul try editing your question. Doesn't exactly make sense right now.

Answer (score 0):

`Thumbnail` and `Giphy` are incompatible types. Either create a mapping function/constructor to switch from one type to another, or combine them both into one type.

For example:

```
class Giphy {
    //...
    Thumbnail toThumbnail()  {
        return new Thumbnail(id,gif,videoUrl,thumbUp,thumbDown);
    }
}
```

And instead of `videoList = new ArrayList<>(giphyList);`

```
final List<Thumbnail> thumbnails = giphyList.stream().map(Giphy::toThumbnail).collect(toList());
```

Comment: its give erroer.

Comment: I have  videoList and giphyList two Arraylist. giphyList value Update in VideoList. videoList value is used for data showing.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is **Object**.

```
ArrayList<Object> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now add thumbnail Arraylist to allItems.

```
allItems.add(thumbnailList);
```

And finally combine giphylist.

```
allItems.addAll(giphylist);
```

To get value from Object ArrayList

```
Thumbnail thumbnail =(Thumbnail)allItems.get(position index);
System.out.println(thumbnail.videoUrl);
```